# zsh temporarily disable alias within a function

Tags: zsh

I feel that `zsh` will expand aliases even it is called within a function, for example

```
alias abc='echo abc'
function fabc(){abc}
```

Is it possible to disable alias expansion in this function?

One more related question: Is it possible to disable alias expansion in the whole interactive shell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable a particular alias with

```sh
unalias abc
```

or all aliases with

```sh
unalias -a
```

Another solution is to force a command not to use an alias with a backslash

```sh
\abc
```

The problem is more difficult when used in a function... It seems from [here](https://ss64.com/bash/alias.html), you cannot define or undefine your aliases in a function.

> Aliases are expanded when a function definition is read, not when the
>   function is executed, because a function definition is itself a
>   compound command.

So you may want to do something like

```sh
alias abc='echo abc'

myaliases=$(alias -L)
unalias -a
function fabc(){
    abc
}
eval $myaliases; unset myaliases

fabc
abc
```

Comment: The first two choices are irreversible. I only want to disable them temporarily within the function. If a plugin loaded uses some command that I happen to have set an alias, will it affect how the plugin behaves? How can I avoid that?

Comment: You can use a subshell with `()` or save your aliases like shown [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161973/clear-or-disable-aliases-in-zsh).

Answer (score 1):

zsh functions support the same options for temporarily ignoring aliases that bash does:

- Surround the command in single or double quotes: `'abc'` or `"abc"`
- Use the `command` command (a zsh built-in): `command abc`
- Put a backslash in front of the command: `\abc`

These all work inside functions as well, so for example:

```
function fabc(){
    'abc'
}
```

Note: if the command has any options or arguments, don't include them in the quotes (if you take that approach), just the command name itself.